# How to get the offset of a text in HTML tag and all the parents to the root tag in PHP?

Tags: php, html, offset, indexof

I extract from an article for example the publicationYear, title and authors like this:

```
$aut = $xpath->query("//table[@cellpadding='6']//b[1]");
$authors = array();
foreach($aut as $node)
    $authors[] = $node->nodeValue;
$title = $doc->getElementsByTagName('h3')->item(1);
$publicationYear = $xpath->query("//p[1]//text()[(following::br)]")->item(0)->nodeValue;
$aux = $xpath->query("//p[2]//text()[(preceding::br)]");
$doi = substr($aux->item($aux->length - 1)->nodeValue, 4);
```

For all strings(the full name, year, title) i need to get even all the tags that come before like :

> form1_table3_tbody1_tr1_td1_table5_tbody1_tr1_td2_p2

and the position in the tag like start: 163,end: 190.
I know only that those informations are grouped in certain tags, but i need to get even the index of the tag if it has siblings that's why the example has table 3 for the third son of forum 1.
If there's a way of doing it in php or at least javascript

**UPDATE**
In te article I have:

```
...
<td valign="top"> 
<h3 class="blue-space">D-Lib Magazine</h3>
<p class="blue">November/December 2014<br>
Volume 20, Number 11/12<br><a href="http://www.dlib.org/dlib/november14/brook/../11contents.html" target="_blank">Table of Contents</a>
</p>
...
```

and the $publicationYear from the first code get this val 2014.
The first code works fine.
I need to create other 3 variables like $fathers =...td1_p1,
$start=18, $end=22

Comment: your question is a bit confusing. please give a simple example input, and corresponding example output. also explain what does not work with your current code, and what error you get, if any.

Comment: still confusing after edit. Where should "td1_p1" come from? What are you trying to achieve exactly? What are yourparsing / transformation rules?

Comment: On the last html example as can you see:
td1 stands for the first <td> ,
p1 stands for the first <p> inside <td> .

And after i got my text I need, inside this paragraph, its coordinates(the index of start and the end);